# RxDataSources itemDeselected not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I'm using RxDataSources and trying to make a "toggle" function for cell selection — i.e., to allow cells (in a single-selection tableView) to be selected and deselected by tapping. I'm using 
`tableView.rx.itemSelected` to get the selection, and `self?.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)` to deselect the cell, if it is currently in the selected state. This seems to basically work, but I want to respond to the deselection. I was assuming that `self?.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)` would result in `tableView.rx.itemDeselected` being called, but that never happens. I'm obviously missing something.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to RxSwift. `itemDeselected` is triggered from the `UITableView` method `UITableViewDelegate.tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)` [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UITableView%2BRx.swift#L176).

According to the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow),`deselectRow(at:animated:)` does not trigger the delegate function `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)`.

This is why it isn't being triggered.

I'd say your best bet is to abstract the logic for cell deselection and use it in both places. You could also call the delegate method yourself but that normally isn't a recommended solution.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. I'll look at an alternative approach. Thanks.